# installer error (windows 7 / vs2010)

Tags: visual-studio, installation

When the installer reaches the point of trying to "tie in" to Visual Studio 2010, ends up generating an error.

```
Error running C:\Program Files\PlasticSCM5/client/tools/regpkg.exe
/root:Software\Micosoft\VisualStudio\10.0 /codebase "C:\Program
Files\PlasticSCM5/client/plasticVSextensibility.dll": regpkgL error:
Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program
Files\PlasticSCM5\client\plasticVSextensibility.dll' or one of its
dependencies.  This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the 
currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
```

Machine:
Windows 7 SP1, 64bit 
Visual Studio 2010 Professional SP1Rel
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.50709 SP1 (and 3.5 and 4.0 installed)

Anyway, this prevents me from getting the "Source Control" option for Plastic SCM in VS.

Anybody got a solution for this ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Install the .NET runtime first, reboot, run windows update and install patches, reboot, and then try the VS2010 installer again.

Comment: Which .Net runtime ?  4.5, 4 and 3.5 are already installed (full versions not just the "client")